# How to encrypt a serialized XML and store in registry

Tags: c#, encryption, xml-serialization, registry

I'm trying to encrypt a serialized XML document and store it in the registry.  I was wondering on how to accomplish that?  I am able to store a non-serialized XML document in the registry by converting the XMLdoc to a byte array, but I'm not sure on how to do it for a serialized XML.

My XML serialization example:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Common.XMLs
{
    [XmlRoot("MyDatabase")]
    public class MyDatabase
    {
        [XmlElement("Item")]
        public Items[] Item; 
    }

    public class Items
    {
        [XmlElement()]
        public string Number;
        [XmlElement()]
        public string Revision;
        [XmlElement()]
        public string DateTimeSet;
        [XmlElement()]
        public string User;
    }
}
```

From this, I would use the XML serialization and deserialization to read and write the file, except that this isn't going to a file, I need to encrypt it and store it in the registry.

Comment: Please make clear what you mean by "serialized XML", and show why you can't convert it to a byte array.

Comment: Using created classes to create/edit the XML document rather than using generic System.Xml classes

Comment: Please show the code you use to serialize the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the byte array of the XML document, it's quite easy:

```
public static byte[] EncryptBytes(byte[] toEncrypt, byte[] key, byte[] IV)
{
    using (RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged())
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, IV))
    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        cs.Write(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

public static byte[] DecryptBytes(byte[] toDecrypt, byte[] key, byte[] IV)
{
    using (RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged())
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = RMCrypto.CreateDecryptor(key, IV))
    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        cs.Write(toDecrypt, 0, toDecrypt.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I have for the XML Document, but I'm looking to encrypt and store Serialized XMLs, not standard XML documents.

Comment: Please explain what a "Serialized XML" is... If you have a byte array, this will encrypt it and decrypt it.

Comment: Using created classes to create/edit the XML document rather than using generic System.Xml classes

Comment: I'm still unsure what that means.  Can you post some of that code into your question?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the Enterprise Library for cryptographic scenarios such as this, it has a lot of utility to it and takes a lot of the overhead out of your code.  Specifically you can use a symmetric encryption algorithm which will spit out a Base64 string that you can then store in the registry.

Check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664686(v=PandP.50).aspx